# Recreate plot when data file changes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

Is it possible to use the `TikZ`/`external` library and have `pgfplots` recreate a figure when a data file that is plotted changes? Say I have something like the following:

`file.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\tikzexternalize
\newcommand{\figFilename}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\figFilename}{thePlot}
    \tikzpicturedependsonfile{\figFilename.tikz}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\figFilename}
    \input{\figFilename.tikz}
    \caption{The caption.}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`thePlot.tikz`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},]
    \addplot+[only marks,mark=x]
      table[x=x,y=y] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

`data.dat`:

```
x y
0 20.44
1 20.06
2 19.76
3 19.54
4 19.40
5 19.34
```

If I change `thePlot.tikz`, the `external` library will detect that the figure is no longer up-to-date and recreate it. Is it possible to have the same effect when any of the plotted data files changes as well? I tried something along the lines of `\tikzpicturedependsonfile{data.dat}`, and it doesn't work. That wouldn't be an ideal solution anyway, as most times I use many data files in each plot and listing all dependent files manually would be more pain than gain.

So is there an easy, automated way for the `external` library to check all data files included in a `tikzpicture` and recreate the plot if at least one of them has changed?

Comment: As far as I know it reads the code not the code contents to compare so that would be difficult (guessing here)

Comment: Are you familiar to arara? You may want to check out the (not yet released) version 4.0. It provides conditionals such as (pseudo-code!!!): arara: pdflatex: if data.dat has changed. Haven't tested or used it, but with that it should be doable.

Comment: @percusse: Yes, I assumed it would be something difficult. It'd be a great feature to have in the `external` library.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I never heard of `arara` before. I'll  have a look as soon as possible. Meanwhile, if you can provide an answer using `arara`, it would be great.

Comment: @sudosensei Sorry, but I don't have the time at the moment. I would love to, as arara is very cool, and I need the conditionals as well, but I am not good in building stuff from source https://github.com/cereda/arara . Maybe Paulo steps over this post and has an idea or I'll post sometime later.

Comment: If you want to have a look: https://github.com/cereda/arara/wiki/Features-in-arara-4.0#check-if-a-file-is-changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

I have committed bugfixes to PGF CVS.

---

**EDIT**

I have taken a closer look after your statement that it does not work despite my assurance that it does.

The answer should probably be "it used to work" - right now, it refrains from doing its job due to two related bugs in the external library.

The external lib seems to *overwrite* the dependencies if it encounters `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` outside of the externalized' pictures environment.

Your occurance of `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` causes this failure (note that you have to move it below `\tikzsetnextfilename`, btw). A solution would be to move this dependency statement into the `thePlot.tikz`, namely into the environment body. But before you do, let me stress that this particular line of code is superfluos if you have a decent PGF version (more recent than pgf 2.10): PGF auto-detects changes inside of the picture environment and recompiles the external file automatically.

If you use PGF 2.10: move your dependency statement into the `tikzpicture` environment of `thePlot.tikz` and you are fine.

If you use a more recent PGF version (i.e. an unstable PGF build): it contains another related bug which also overwrites the dependency file. In this case: proceed as in the last paragraph, but also call `\tikzexternalize[up to date check=simple]` in your externalization statement - this deactivates the up-to-date check.

I will fix both bugs in PGF and will post an update here once it is ready. The bugfix will (hopefully) allow you to use both requested features out-of-the-box as outlined in my original answer (see below).

---

The mentioned/requested features

- recompile externalized pdf if the content of the `tikzpicture` environment changes
- recompile externalized pdf if the content of an included data file `data.dat` changes

are already available. The first item works out-of-the-box if and only if you have a PGF version which is more recent than 2.10 (as you already mentioned; I'd just like to stress it here).

The second point works if and only if you use `\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]`. As soon as you do, it works out-of-the-box because `pgfplots` always calls `\tikzpicturedependsonfile{<filename>.<ext>}` whenever it executes an `\addplot table {<filename>}`.

Currently, the external lib ignores `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` unless you use `mode=list and make`.

Note that `make` is precisely what you want here: you have a sequence of files as dependencies and you need to execture a couple of "targets" whenever one of these files is more recent than the other ones.

Comment: I am using `mode=list and make`, but the plot is not recreated when a data file changes. Is this because I invoke `\tikzpicturedependsonfile{thePlot.tikz}` manually and this prevents the `external` library from appending the rest of the dependencies?

Comment: @sudosensei I have committed bugfixes to PGF CVS. It will become part of the next stable.

Comment: That is great. Thank you, Christian. Just to clarify: if I use the latest development version of `PGF`, the features requested will work out-of-the-box when using `mode=list and make`, without needing to use `\tikzpicturedependsonfile<file.ext>`. Is that right?

Comment: @sudosensei Yes, right.